# When form validation fails, how to pass error information for new try?

Tags: php, validation

I'm developing a form validation class in PHP. When form validation fails, I can easily redirect again to the form's html page but without error information. I would like to redirect to the form's page with the specific errors about which fields failed and why.

How should I do this? Should I send information back via GET or POST? and in which format? Would really to see some code to see how people tackled this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the header() function. So just check the fields that are posted:

```
if(!$form->valid()){
    $msg = "Form is not valid";
} else { 
    //Don't know if you want this
    $msg = "Form is valid";
}

header("Location: [page where you came from]?msg=" . urlencode($msg));
```

Then in the page where you're redirecting to use

```
if(isset($_GET['msg]))
    echo urldecode($_GET['msg']);
```

to echo the message. If you are using other get variables in the location of the header function, of course, use `&msg=" . urlencode($msg)`. (You may also want to return the values that the user submitted, so the user doesn't have to fill out the entire form again if he makes 1 mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with user187291's suggestion of using `$_SESSION` because:

- It doesn't hijack the URI like using `$_GET` (you would never want a static link to a status message). Users could press "back" to the page with your form and still see a status message because the URI says so.
- Print and unset it in the same run, you won't be able to use it more than once (which is what you want?!)

If you're going with AJAX, `$_GET` is more widely used for retreiving values, which you are doing from the validation controller.

Comment: If you agree with it, how come it has zero upvotes at this time?

Comment: @Sam: Well, I *partly* agree with it but not with "do not redirect after failure, just output form again along with error messages" since that would cause the back button to hang up. Feel free to upvote it yourself, by all means :) Btw, your website is unavailable!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I must have forgotten that I changed the url to be less redundant at some point

Answer (score 1):

there are number of approaches

- pass errors in GET when redirecting back like you said
- use sessions to store error info, on the form page check Session for errors
- do not redirect after failure, just output form again along with error messages
- ajax submits

which one to use depends on the application. For most apps sessions method is most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

// Pseudo Code

```
function isValid($parm) {
   $return = false;
   if(preg_match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/, $parm) {
      $return = true;
   }
   return $return;
}

$firstname = $_GET["fname"];
$lastname  = $_GET["lname"];

$validFirstName = isValid($firstname);
$validLastName  = isValid($lastname);

if($validFirstName == true && $validLastName == true) {
   echo "It's all good";
   // Do what you need to like, Submit
} else {
   echo "Please retry";
   // Display error message
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that is going to render information in the action page. I would like to go back to the form's page and render erros there, for each field, next to it.

Comment: This would keep you on the same page unless validation passes, then redirect/submit/etc...

Answer (score 0):

I use a class to interface with $_POST, similar to the following:

```
// create the object
$post = new PostData();

// register your requirements... write whatever methods you need
// for each call,read $_POST, check criteria, and mark the field
// as good or bad...
$post->required ('LastName');
$post->required ('FirstName');
$post->numeric ('Age');
$post->optional ('MiddleInitial');
$post->regExp ('/\d{3}/','AreaCode');
$post->email ('Email');

// check the status
if (!$post->isValid ())
{
    $_SESSION['FailedPostData'] = $post;
    header ('Location: page.php');
}

// normal form processing
```

Then, on page.php, you can see if FailedPostData is in the session, read it to find the info entered last time, as well as which fields that failed. I use a template engine with macros that let me easily re-populate the form inputs and mark the failures. Otherwise you might end up with lots of code for a simple form...

You'll also need a mechanism to be sure that stale FailedPostData doesn't hang around in the session and confuse things.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it this way. Beginner in php so not sure if this is the best way to do:

HTML Form Page:

```
<form id="abc" method="post" action="validate.php">
```

PHP Page
..validation conditions..call a function if things do not match

```
function display_error($error) {
        echo "<html><body><link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><br><center><h2>";
        echo "$error";
        echo "</h2></center><br><br>";
        echo "<center><input type='button' value='Go Back' onClick='history.go(-1)' style='width:100px; height:28px; font-size:16px'></center>";
        echo "</body></html>";
    }
```

Clicking on the back button takes you back to the html page with the data intact.